# Delphi 10.3 (Rio) Community Edition, opening project doesn't open any source files

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.3-rio

I have installed Delphi 10.3 (Rio) Community Edition on two workstations. Both installations have the same issue.

When I open a Delphi project, none of the source files or form units are opened along with it. I have to either open them manually or via *Project > View source* and *Open file at cursor*

I have Delphi 10.4 (Sydney) Professional installed on my company laptop. Here it works as expected; upon opening the project, at least the main form unit is opened along with it.

Is this a setting that I'm overlooking, or is it just the way the community edition IDE works now?

Comment: In Tools->Options->Environment Options->AutoSave options, check *Project Desktop*.

Comment: @KenWhite This seems to work alright for my purpose. For comparison, I looked up the same setting on my company laptop, but it's unchecked there. Must be something else at play here, but this solution is satisfactory. If you'll post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Does your project folder on the laptop have a YourProjectName.dsk file in it? It may be that it was previously turned on (which created the .dsk file) by someone else on another machine, and the file just came over to your laptop with the code when you copied it. Turning off the option doesn't remove the existing file, it just stops updating it.

Comment: @KenWhite No, there are no .dsk files in the project folders on the laptop. I'm also the only one using the laptop, and the Delphi installation is relatively fresh. That said, both the home workstations have a few weeks old installations of Delphi CE. Except for some library paths additions and autocomplete settings, the configurations for all are pretty much left alone since installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the IDE to remember which files you have open by checking *Project Desktop* in *Tools->Options->Environment Options->Autosave options*.

In Delphi 10.4 Sydney, the setting has been relocated to *Tools->Options->IDE->Saving and Desktop->Autosave*, where the checkbox is captioned *Save project desktop when closing*.